# How to compare two columns in Excel and if match, then copy the cell next to it

Tags: excel, match, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've tried 
`=IF(ISNUMBER(ISMATCH(D2,G:G,0)),H:H,"")` to match numbers with a key, here are my rules:

`Column D` (starting at D2) match with `Column G` (starts at D2 as well)

If match, then Copy the cell in `Column H` that is matched through `Columns D and G` to `Columns E`

Is there a way to do this with a formula?

**Summary**

Column E is empty at the start, I want to copy the content of Column H to this column, but only if the row has been matched with column D and G.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might be easier with vlookup. Try this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,G:H,2,0),"")
```

The `IFERROR()` is for no matches, so that it throws `""` in such cases.

`VLOOKUP`'s first parameter is the value to 'look for' in the reference table, which is column G and H.

`VLOOKUP` will thus look for `D2` in column G and return the value in the column index `2` (column G has column index 1, H will have column index 2), meaning that the value from column H will be returned.

The last parameter is `0` (or equivalently `FALSE`) to mean an exact match. That's what you need as opposed to approximate match.

Comment: Is there a way to iterate D2 value to D3,D4,D5... ect? Yes change D2 to D:D

Comment: @GivenPie I'm not sure what you mean by iterating the D2 to D3, D4 and D5... Care to elaborate?

Comment: The formula above will calculate one cell's data. Therefore if I have a list of a thousand rows, I can just replace `D2` with `D:D` to represent the column

Comment: @GivenPie Oh, you just drag the formula down to as far as possible. The values in column D unique, right?

Answer (score 1):

try this formula in column E:

> =IF( AND( ISNUMBER(D2), D2=G2), H2, "")

your error is the number test, ISNUMBER( ISMATCH(D2,G:G,0) )

you do check if ismatch is-a-number, (i.e. isNumber("true") or isNumber("false"), which is not!.

I hope you understand my explanation.